# Проблема миграции Birt report с weblogic на apache-tomee-plume-7.1.3

Tags: jdbc, tomee, birt

Занимаюсь миграцией JavaEE приложения с вебложика на томкат.
Возникла проблема, при генерации отчета не подтягиваются данные из бд.
Опытным путем выяснил в чем проблема: в файлах шаблона(*.rptdesign) указано odaJndiName

`<property name="odaJndiName">appdb</property>`

и по нему не находит в томкате связи с бд.
Если я к appdb добавлю префикс java:comp/env/, то всё замечательно работает.
Подскажите плиз как в томкате настроить автоматическую подстановку этого префикса?

**context.xml**

```
<Context useNaming="false">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <ResourceLink global="appdb" name="appdb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

</Context>
```

**server.xml**

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- TomEE plugin for Tomcat -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" /> 
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
              
    <Resource name="pivdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="user" password="password"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    initialSize="5" 
    maxWaitMillis="1200000"
    maxTotal="120" 
    maxIdle="5"
    validationQuery="select 1"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
<Service name="Catalina">  
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="120000"
               redirectPort="8443"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml"
               compression="on" compressionMinSize="8192" useSendfile="false"
               maxThreads="3800"
               xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```